# Show any open interval is homeomorphic to R.

Tags: general-topology

Show that any open interval $(a,b), (a,\infty), (-\infty,b)$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. I already know that $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

> We know $(-1,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$ are homeomorphic, then we define a suitable homeomorphism $f:(-1,1) \implies \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)= \dfrac{x}{1-|x|}$.

So I want to know how to prove that $(a,\infty), (-\infty,b)$ are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Try transformations of $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\ln : (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a homeomorphism.

Comment: such as f(1,∞)=R by f(x)=inx